# Importing .py file of outer module from inner module

Tags: python, file, import

The structure is:

```
hello/
    __init__.py
    params.py
    bye/
        __init__.py
        params2.py
```

I want to call constant `A` that lives in params from params2 file...

I tried:

```
from ..hello.params import A
```

But I get the following error:

```
ValueError: Attempted relative import in non-package
```

`hello` is not a package?
Thanks in advance!!!

Comment: If you're specifying the full path from the top level, you don't need the periods. `from hello.param import A`

Answer (score 0):

Your code is not working because you are trying to import something that is one level up relative to the directory `hello`

To make it work you need to be aware what is your PYTHONPATH. If there is `hello/bye` in PYTHONPATH, this may work:

```
from ..params import A
```

It might be also the case that there is your project root `hello` in PYTHONPATH, then you may just do

```
from params import A
```

All depends on how you have installed your package or which IDE config you are currently using or which path you have explicitely added to PYTHONPATH